# Unresolved external symbol error when using class object with vector

Tags: c++, vector

Currently trying to use vectors to store bullets in a game. 
when i attempt to use push_back to add a new object to the list i get an unresolved external symbol error. I've tried changing it to an integer and the vector works so i doubt its a linker error?
my vector is initialised in my main CPP and is then passed a few times to this the function within a separate class.

Here's my code:

```
void Hero::shoot(std::vector<Bullet> bullets)
{
    Bullet firedBullet();
    bullets.push_back(firedBullet());
}
```

My error is:

> LNK2019   unresolved external symbol "class Bullet __cdecl
>   firedBullet(void)" (?firedBullet@@YA?AVBullet@@XZ) referenced in
>   function "public: void __thiscall Hero::shoot(class std::vector >)"
>   (?shoot@Hero@@QAEXV?$vector@VBullet@@V?$allocator@VBullet@@@std@@@std@@@Z)    Project1    H:\C++\Project1\Project1\Hero.obj

Please Help.

Comment: "i doubt its a linker error" unresolved references are always linker errors.

Comment: Of course it's a linker error. The linker is complaining after all. You didn't provide enough code to figure out the exact cause, so please provide a [mcve]. Having said that, this question is probably a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix

Comment: `Bullet firedBullet();` -- This does not do what you think it does.  It does not declare an instance of `Bullet`.  I bet the linker is complaining about your bogus `fireBullet()` function.  Why not post the linker error?

Comment: Most vexing parse, `Bullet firedBullet();` forward declares a function called `firedBullet` that returns a `Bullet` and takes no arguments. Then in `bullets.push_back(firedBullet());` the compiler thinks you're calling that function but the linker can't find a definition for it.

Comment: Excuse me thus us my first post still getting getting to grips with how to pose my questions etc. By linker error I meant an I messed up a an external depency link sorry for being so unclear. Will check out the linked post.

Comment: @Pyrous The linker emitted an error to you -- just copy and paste that error message in your post.  Right now you got an answer based on wrong C++ coding that would cause a certain linker error, but we don't know for sure until you post that error.

Comment: @Pyrous -- As you can see, the linker error mentions `firedBullet`, just as the comments and answers suggested.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie thanks, I'll make sure to include in future posts.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you have declared and called a function that has no definition.

```
Bullet firedBullet();
```

declares a function that takes no parameters and returns a `Bullet`.

```
bullets.push_back(firedBullet());
```

calls that function and thus you get a linker error.
(I suspect that you added the parentheses on `firedBullet`to make it compile?)

It should be

```
Bullet firedBullet;
bullets.push_back(firedBullet);
```

or

```
bullets.push_back(Bullet());
```

or

```
bullets.emplace_back();
```

Comment: Or it can be `bullets.push_back(Bullet());` without the intermediate declaration.